# How to change the format of the column Person in a contact list

Tags: sharepoint-online, person-or-group, column-formatting

When I use a contact list with a column "Person" it displays the person's name and last name in a certain format.

Ex: Melone (Jack)

But I just want the first name and then the last name.

Ex: Jack Melone

Is that possible, if so how can I do that?

Greetings,

P

Comment: Are you using Modern experience or classic experience?

Comment: Modern experience

Comment: Does changing the field settings in list settings work?

Comment: Yes it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the display format of the Person field when editing the column's settings.  Find the "Show field" dropdown in the column settings, and experiment with the options:

[image]

In my test list, selecting "Name" or "Name (with presence)" yields the correct results.

Comment: "Name" or "Name (with presence)" still returns "last name, first name". You still need to manipulate that t get what the op asked for.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way, we can create a Calculated column "Person" with the Formula below.

```
=[First Name]&" "&[Last Name]
```

[image]